# Changing from BLOB to filestorage - mySQL tweaks

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I took over a project some time ago, where file binaries were stored as BLOBs. Those were from sizes of 0.5-50 Mb, therefore that table was touched as less as possible (-> eBeans lazyloading etc). The BLOB stuff worked quite fine as long as the whole system was running on one dedicated server, once we switched to AWS EC2 instances + RDS, things were (obviously) slower.

Therefore I switched the data storage from BLOB to S3 (+ reference to the bucket/key stored in the DB), which is much faster for our backend and our clients.

Now my question is, obviously the programmer before set up the mySQL DB to handle bigger chunks of data (max packagesize etc), and I also stumbled over some discussion about connection pool size.

What are critical parameters to check in the mySQL setup, and what are effective ways of evaluating them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely answer to your question is "change nothing."

MySQL has many, many, many "tunable" parameters, and there is an absolute wealth of bad advice available online about "optimizing" them.  But this is a temptation best avoided.

To the extent that system variables have been changed from defaults, if you ever find yourself in a situation where you believe tweaking the configuration is necessary, your *first instinct* should be to revert settings to their defaults unless you have a specific and justified reason not to.

Settings like `max_allowed_packet` if set too small, will break some things (like large blobs) but if set larger than necessary will have little or no impact... the "excess" isn't allocated or otherwise harmful.  In the case of `max_allowed_packet`, this does impose a constraint on memory use by limiting the amount of memory the server would ever need to allocate for a single packet, but since it's a brick wall limit, you don't necessarily want to shrink it.  If you aren't sending packets that big, it isn't hurting anything.

> It is safe to increase the value of this variable because the extra memory is allocated only when needed. For example, mysqld allocates more memory only when you issue a long query or when mysqld must return a large result row. The small default value of the variable is a precaution to catch incorrect packets between the client and server and also to ensure that you do not run out of memory by using large packets accidentally.
>
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/packet-too-large.html

Other parameters, though, can have dramatically counter-intuitice [negative effects](https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/11/16/table_cache-negative-scalability/) because the range of "valid" values is a superset of the range of "optimal" values.  The query cache is a prime example of this. "But it's more cache! How can that be bad?!" Well, a bigger house increases the amount of housework you have to do, and the query cache is a big house with only one tiny broom (a global mutex that each thread contends for when entering and leaving).

Still others, like `innodb_buffer_pool_size` only really have one relatively small optimal range of values for a given server.  Too small will increase disk I/O and impair performance because the pool is smaller than the system could support, too large will increase disk I/O due to the server using swap space or crash it entirely by exhausting the system of every last available kilobyte of free RAM.

Perhaps you get the idea.

Unless you have a specific parameter that you believe may be suboptimally configured, leave a working system working.  If you change things, change them one at a time, and prove or disprove that each change was a good idea before proceeding.  If you are using a non-default value, consider the default as a potentially good candidate value.

And stay away from "tuning scripts" that make suggestions about parameters you should change.  Those are interesting to look at, but their advice is often dangerous.  I've often thought about writing my own one of these, but all it would do is check for values not set to the default and tell the user to explain themselves or set it back. :)  Maybe that would catch on.

Comment: It was my haunch to revert to default settings, since my DB without the BLOBs is actually pretty much "default", speaking of fields, data amount etc. .. and since I didn't initialize the DB in the first place, I am not exactly sure which parameters are off defaults. I thought there might be some "critical" parameters which I could check manually. But I will follow your suggestion, revert to default and see where that puts me. Thank you a lot for your answer! I will keep the question open for 1-2 days, maybe someone still has a point to add. Otherwise I will mark your reply as answer. :)